# Is there a way to format html for an [epub] to show chapter title on each page?

Tags: html, css, epub

I'm trying to reformat some [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org) texts to give myself what I consider attractive epubs, and specifically I'm trying to get the chapter headings that appear in the main body flow of the text to be appropriately centred on each page, whether at the top or the bottom I don't really mind. 
I just about grok html, and suspect that the reflow of text on different readers, potentially with different font sizes that the user can specify "at run time" means this isn't readily achieved, a suspicion that reading a few beginners guides (e.g. [Guido Henkel's series extolling the virtues of diligent epub formatting](http://guidohenkel.com/?p=57)) has reinforced, but I feel like I've seen such formatting once or twice: if only I could remember where, I could just look at the relevant epubs.

Can anyone either specifically recommend how this could be achieved, or help me find a more comprehensive guide to html & css as it applies to epubs?

Comment: Curious how the question is unclear, but in case someone's downvoted on the basis of perceived low research effort, these are the resources I've looked at in attempt to work out whether chapter headings are possible:
- [Introduction to CSS & HTML for epub](https://prezi.com/1jest0cxt2hp/an-introduction-to-html-and-css-for-epub/)
- [InDesign to epub](http://www.digitalbookworld.com/resources-going-from-indesign-to-ebook/)
- [Jedi Saber](http://www.jedisaber.com/eBooks/formatsource.shtml)
- [OPS specification](http://www.idpf.org/epub/20/spec/OPS_2.0.1_draft.htm#Section2.0)

Answer (score 0):

[Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com) is an application which lets the user create and edit ePub files. Actually an ePub file is a zip file that contains html pages, css, fonts and ebook metadata. You can download a free ebook then use calibre to see its structure and understand how it works.

Add in each chapter page a tag like the following, right after the body tag:

```
<h1>Chapter X</h1>
```

Then add in the css file this code:

```
h1 { text-align: center; }
```

And you will get what you where looking for.
(If it doesn’t it’s because there are some css conflicting properties)

If you need to understand how html and css work, [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com) can probably help you.